# Creating a custom Ubuntu installation DVD : Setting custom preferences

Tags: system-installation

I am aware of these documents:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization
http://blog.self.li/post/74294988486/creating-a-post-installation-script-for-ubuntu
on making custom Ubuntu installation CD or DVD media.  It's particularly clear on adding custom packages to the install.

But how can I customize user preferences, such as sleep timing or package update policy?  I'd like to do this either as a custom installation CD, or at least as a click to execute script.  The goal is to set up a bunch of machines, all with the same preferences settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty programs that permit you do that. For me, one of the easiest one is `remastersys`.

1- Custom your Ubuntu with all the preference you want to have on the new iso.

2- Download remastersys. First you will need to add the repository:

```
vi /etc/apt/sources.list

# Remastersys
deb http://www.remastersys.klikit-linux.com/repository remastersys/
```

Save and exit. Run

```
 apt-get update
```

Install it

```
apt-get install remastersys
```

3- Now you just need to run to create the copy of your system:

```
sudo remastersys dist
```

This also lets you create backups on iso file, with the following command:

```
sudo remastersys backup nameyouwant.iso
```